# How to dynamically allocate memory for const char double pointer (using new)

Tags: c++

I create a pointer to an array of pointers to char arrays (double ptr):

```
const char **strptr = new const char*[str_arr.size()]; //str_arr.size() = number of strings
```

I then try to dynamically allocate memory for each of the individual pointers to the strings:

```
for (int i=0; i < str_arr.size(); i++) {
  size_t len = str_arr[i].length(); //length of each string
  strptr[i] = new char[len+1]; //+1 for null character
  strcpy(strptr[i], vars[i]->name().c_str()); // errors here
}
```

I then use the double pointer in functions, etc.

```
somefxn(strptr); ...
```

Then deallocate the memory:

```
for (int i=0; i< str_arr.size(); i++) { delete [] strptr[i]; }
delete [] strptr;
```

Seems like I've covered the necessary bases. But, I get these errors on the strcpy line:

```
"error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' ",
"error: initializing argument 1 of 'char* strcpy(char*, const char*)' "
```

Seems like a simple type issue, so I changed this line:

```
strptr[i] = new const char[len+1];
```

Same errors, and this new one on the strptr[i] line:

```
"error: uninitialized const in 'new' of 'const char' "
```

Not sure what to make of this. I think I'm overlooking a detail with the pointers and memory allocation, but haven't figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using manual memory management rather than containers and/or smart pointers? We are not writing C++98 anymore (if we can help it)...

Comment: `strptr`'s type is a pointer to `const char`. Because of that, you can't copy into the area it points to - it points to `const`-qualified object. You might want to remove `const` qualifier from your `strptr` definition.

Comment: I assume all of this ugly memory management + cstrings is an academic exercise. You probably should mention your requirements.

Comment: Use a `std::vector<std::string>>` for heavens sake!

Comment: @JesperJuhl OP is clearly using containers in other parts of the code, so we should assume there is a reason to use manual memory management here (most likely, OP is doing this on their professor's behest)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ OP already has one :)

Comment: Please assemble a [mcve]. It is much harder to help you beat snippets into shape than it is a program. As an added bonus, producing such a program often exposes the error to you and allows you to fix it without asking a question.

Comment: @SergeyA Can't spot it in the question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `i< str_arr.size();` - looks like `str_arr` is a vector of strings.

Comment: @SergeyA "OP is clearly using containers in other parts of the code" - Huh? How do you know? That's not at all clear to me from the question.

Comment: @JesperJuhl what else `name().c_str()` or `str_arr.size()` could signify? The first is obviously `std::string`, the later is (likely) an `std::vector`.

Comment: @SergeyA Fair enough. I missed that.

Comment: I do not understand why people are downvoting and closing the question. This is answerable question, which provides a snippet of code and errors, and is clear.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> strcpy(strptr[i], vars[i]->name().c_str()); // errors here
> ```

Since you declared `strptr` as

```
const char **strptr = ...
```

The compiler does not allow you to change anything that `strptr[i]` points to. Remove the `const`.

```
char **strptr = ...
```

---

Unless you are required to use `char** strptr` for reasons beyond your control, you should switch to using `std::string` and `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<std::string> str_array;
```

That will obviate the need for writing a bunch of errorprone code.

Answer (score 0):

`const char **strptr = new const char*[5];`

Is a **non-const** pointer to a **non-const** pointer to **const** char.

You can modify the double pointer by doing e.g. `strptr++;` or `strptr=nullptr;`.

You can modify the individual pointers like `strptr[i]= new const char[2]{'a', 'b'};` or `strptr[i]++;`.

But you cannot modify the **const** char value i.e `strptr[i][j]='b';` won't work. 
`std::strcpy` tries to do just that and compiler rightfully complains of course.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, avoid using owning bare pointers. They are usually hardly ever needed. You appear to be allocating arrays. The simplest solution to allocate memory for an array is `std::vector`, or specifically for character strings, `std::string`.

The most efficient way of storing an array of arrays is a flat array containing all elements. In this case an appropriate solution is a single `std::string`. If you have a function that takes a `const char **` as an argument, you can use an array of `const char*` pointers to offsets into that string container.

Comment: Downvoting for not actually answering OPs question, which is answerable. The nudge into idiomatic C++ could be appreciated as an addition to an answer.

Comment: @SergeyA OP's question is how to dynamically allocate memory using new. I've answered the ideal way to do that. The question doesn't exclude the possibility of using containers.

Comment: Your answer shows OP how not to allocate using new. This is not what OP asked for. There could be valid reasons for OP to need manual memory management (of which academic exercise is the most common one).

Comment: @SergeyA OP didn't ask how to manage memory manually,nor did they say that the need to do such thing. I've described in my answer how to use new to allocate dynamic memory: By doing indirectly using containers.

Comment: But they did! Here is question title, copied verbatim with my highlighting: "How to dynamically allocate memory for const char double pointer **(using new)**"

Comment: @SergeyA that doesn't contradict what I said. You can use new indirectly by using allocators and containers,and that is in fact a better way than not using them.

Comment: Not downvoting, but this really does not answer OP's question. You did not explain the compilation errors. I agree with what you wrote, but that should be an "educational bonus". Saying "you're doing it wrong, do it like this instead" is not enough.